# how can I pass a data from a UICollectionView indexwise

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I previously passed some data from a **tableView** like this:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if( segue.identifier == "productList_to_detail" ) {

        let VC1 = segue.destination as! ShopItemVC
        if afData == 1 {
          if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let productIdToGet = sCategory[indexPath.row]
                VC1.product_id = productIdToGet.product_id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see when I tap on a particular **Cell** it grabs some data from it and pass the data relative to the **Cell** . Now I want to do the same but with a **CollectionView**. When I tap on a particular **item** of the **CollectionView** I want to grab some value from it and pass it through **segue** . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the selected cell's data of `collectionView` in `prepare(for:sender:)` method it depends on how you have created segue in storyboard.

- If `Segue` is created from `UICollectionViewCell` to Destination `ViewController`.

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

      if( segue.identifier == "productList_to_detail" ) {

          let VC1 = segue.destination as! ShopItemVC
          if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell,
             let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {

                let productIdToGet = sCategory[indexPath.row]
                VC1.product_id = productIdToGet.product_id
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- If `Segue` is created from Source `ViewController` to Destination `ViewController`.

  ```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //Pass indexPath as sender
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "productList_to_detail", sender: indexPath)
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

      if( segue.identifier == "productList_to_detail" ) {

          let VC1 = segue.destination as! ShopItemVC
          if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {

                let productIdToGet = sCategory[indexPath.row]
                VC1.product_id = productIdToGet.product_id
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: ohh that helped @NiravD

Comment: @ArafinMacRussell Welcome mate :)